# create map of string slice in go

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

I am try to create a map of string slice with the code in GO

```
newMap := map [string][]string{
    "first" : {
        "good", "bad"
    },
    "second" : {
        "top", "bottom"
    }
}
```

It seems not to be the right way, what is the wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a comma `,` at the end of each initializer list.

```
newMap := map [string][]string{
    "first" : {
        "good", "bad",
    },
    "second" : {
        "top", "bottom",
    },
}
```

You can find a working example [here](http://play.golang.org/p/Uq1XJlS9LM).

Comment: @Intermernet Thanks! I used your code but with slightly changes.

Comment: what a meaningless comma, especially in the slice !

Comment: I actually find this comma really convenient as it allows adding/removing/commenting out map/slice elements in the same way no matter whether they are in the middle or at the end.